# Убрать отступы внутри QChartView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Добрый день. Имеется виджет QChartView содержащий в себе QChart:

```
auto* chart = new QChart();
chart->addSeries(barseries);
chart->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0); // пытаюсь установить отступы вручную
_chartView->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0); // и тут тоже

_chartView->setChart(chart);
_chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

ui->histLayout->addWidget(_chartView.get());
```

В результате я получаю такой график:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако мне нужно убрать отступы, помеченные красным и зеленым цветом на картинке. Серая область - это `_chartView`.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: setGeometry() вызовите для виджетов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена установкой отрицательных отступов:

```
chart->setContentsMargins(-11,-11,-11,-11);
```